# ASP.NET Core 2 Web API - 502 Bad Gate Way(Centos 7) - NGINX

Tags: linux, nginx, server, centos, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an **ASP.NET Core 2 Web API project** and **Centos 7 Linux server**.

I ran the project in my server as a service.

It is running 7/24 in my server.

If I write to Linux terminal **"wget http://localhost:5000/api/users --no-check-certificate"**, users json file download to my server. There is no problem here.

But I can't access to my api from my local computer.

If I write **"http://[SERVER_IP]:[PORT]/api/users"** to a web browser, it returns **502 Bad Gateway** Http Status Code.

How can I fix it?

**etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
http {
      ...
      server{
         listen 12900;
         location / {
            proxy_pass http://195.201.150.228:5000;
         }
      } 
}
```

[image: Photo]

Comment: You're proxying request to `http://195.201.150.228:5000`. Have you configured your server to open the port of `5000`?

Comment: Yes i already open port 5000 in vesta c panel.

Comment: Can you access the `http://195.201.150.228:5000` from a remote computer ?

Comment: I solved the problem. My server has vesta c panel. so i must not write the server block to the **etc/nginx/nginx.conf**. I created a user and a subdomain which is named **api.hocamnerede.com** and i wrote the server block to **/home/Hocamnerede/conf/web/api.hocamnerede.com.nginx.conf**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. My server has vesta c panel. so i must not write the server block to the **etc/nginx/nginx.conf**. I created a user and a subdomain which is named **api.hocamnerede.com** and i wrote the server block to **/home/Hocamnerede/conf/web/api.hocamnerede.com.nginx.conf**.

**/home/Hocamnerede/conf/web/api.hocamnerede.com.nginx.conf**

```
server {
listen      195.201.150.228:80;
server_name api.hocamnerede.com www.api.hocamnerede.com;
root        /home/Hocamnerede/web/api.hocamnerede.com/public_html;
index       index.php index.html index.htm;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/api.hocamnerede.com.log combined;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/api.hocamnerede.com.bytes bytes;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/api.hocamnerede.com.error.log error;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am anticipating the reason behind **502 bad gateway and http request blocked by CORS policy in ASP.NET Core**

because of deadlock in the database also we may get 502 bad gate way error in browser console.

**database deadlock :**   We are trying to get/put data asynchronously in database there db is getting locked due large amount of transactions and service is not getting any response.

**solution :** We can resolve this issue by **increase the timeout** in web.config file

**solution :**  Either we should keep on clear the all sessions in db side else we should convert all async insert/select/update methods to sync in service side.

**side effect for sync calls :** We are going to loose our application performance.